# Perl or Batch for fetching information from excel and pasting in other excel

Tags: perl, batch-file

I have folders which has numbers as name of the folders and one **New** excel sheet and one **Main** excel sheet with information related to the folder names. So i have a requirement like 
 1) i have to fetch the folder name one by one from the main excel sheet and if it founds the name in the excel sheet it should get the whole row content of that cell and paste it in the new excel sheet. Like that it should fetch for all the folders.

Comment: Sounds interesting. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have a batch script where i am renaming the folders according to the numbers in the excel sheet but i want to know can we access information from excel using batch script

Comment: You could use a hybrid batch/VBS file to do it. I think you'd be better off just doing it all in Excel VBA though.

Comment: If you need to do it in Perl, you could use [Win32 OLE](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1709/lib/Win32/OLE.pm)

Comment: i have tried a perl script which is giving the following error as Can't call method "Worksheet" on unblessed reference at Excel-extract.pl line 14  and the below is the code

Answer (score 0):

- There are plenty of modules in CPAN for reading and writing Excel, though none are perfect.
- For more power, you can use Python to control OfficeLibre.
- If you don't mind Google, you can use the [Google Drive APIs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) to upload, manipulate, create, and export files.
- If you need better Excel support than that, you're stuck with VB or macros inside of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Batch is not a very good programming language. The Unix BASH shell simply leaves it in the dust. It was never really designed to be anything more than a way to setup an environment, or to startup a few DOS based programs. Although a few additions have been made in Batch since Windows came out, it still feels like Microsoft abandoned it long ago.

However, every single Windows PC comes built in with an extremely powerful and object oriented scripting language called [PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx). Not only is PowerShell potent, but it can easily interact with any  [Microsoft Office document](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2010/08/19/automating-office-and-excel-in-powershell.aspx) including Excel.

There's only one minor problem with PowerShell: No one knows it.

A couple of years ago, I was at a Windows based office where they needed email alerts sent out if files were not getting updated (three different alert levels). Well, that's no problem with either Python or Perl. Shouldn't take me more than a few hours to throw something together.

For security reason, they didn't want to install Python or Perl or anything else on their system. That's when I turned to PowerShell.

PowerShell did the trick. It could do anything that Python or Perl could do, and although its syntax was a bit weird, it was extremely consistent. However, this project proved to be a lonely trek. Despite the fact that Powershell is ubiquitous in the Windows World and powerful, few people know it or use it. I haven't touched PowerShell since.

If the choice is between Perl and Batch, choose Perl. The Perl module [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet%3a%3aParseExcel) will do what you want.

However, if you're in the Windows World, and you interact with a lot of Microsoft Office documents, it is worth your time to learn PowerShell.